# Node Express Cors issue

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I cant figure why the cors express middleware wont work. cors, express, and ejs are all saved in package.json. The app works fine if I add corsanywhere proxy on the front end but id like to work around this on the server side. any help much appreciated I've been stuck on this.

the api is in the get View/index path

the error is:
  Access to fetch at 'https://api.darksky.net/forecast/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const ejs = require('ejs');
const cors = require('cors');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// app.use((req, res, next) => {
//   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
//   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin', 'X-Requested-With')
//   next();
// });

app.use(cors());


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/Public'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', cors(), (req, res) => {
   res.render(__dirname + '/Views/index')
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`server is listening on ${PORT}`)
});
```

client side:

it works with the ${proxy} in there but id like to get rid of that

```````
    if(navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        long = position.coords.longitude;
        lat = position.coords.latitude;

        var proxy = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' 
        var api = `${proxy}https://api.darksky.net/forecast/042750f3abefefdfe2c9d43cf33ce576/${lat},${long}`;
        fetch(api)
        .then(response => {
        return response.json(); 
    })

.then(data => {
let {temperature, summary, icon,} = data.currently;

            temperatureDegree.textContent = Math.floor(temperature);
            temperatureDescription.textContent = summary;
            locationTimezone.textContent = data.timezone;
            setIcons(icon, document.querySelector('.icon'
w

``````
```````

Comment: Define “won’t work”.

Comment: Show the request that you're trying to send cross origin. We need to see exactly what that request looks like.  And, we want to see exactly what the error is.

Comment: Can you show the code for the client-side request so we can see exactly what type of request you're sending, what content-type, what custom headers, etc..?  That determines what level of CORs support is needed.

Comment: So, if you're trying to access some other service `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/` t(hat you don't control) from your web page, then there is nothing you can do to make CORs work for that.  It's up to the `api.darksky.net` server to decide if CORs is allowed or not.  You can't change that.  You could have your web page ask your server to get some data from `api.darksky.net` for you and then return it back to your webpage (working as a simple proxy).  Your server is not subject to any CORs limitations when accessing `api.darksky.net`.  Only browsers are limited by CORs.

Comment: ok that makes sense thanks.

Comment: could you show how you are connecting to api.darksky.net? The problem doesn't seem to be in the code you provided, but in the code that invokes that other service. There is a difference between enabling CORS for your server (that is what you did with express) and api.darksy.net enabling CORS for their server.

Comment: added above in post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you're trying to access some other service `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/` (that you don't control) from your web page, then there is nothing you can do to make CORs work for that. It's up to the `api.darksky.net` server to decide if CORs is allowed or not. You can't change that.

You could make a request from your web page to your server to ask it to get some data from `api.darksky.net` for you and then return it back to your webpage (working as a simple proxy). Your server is not subject to any CORs limitations when accessing `api.darksky.net`. Only browsers are limited by CORs.

And, as you've found, you can also use a proxy service that enables CORs and fetches data for you.

Let's suppose you want to proxy the parts of the darksky API, you could do something simple like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const request = require('request');
const apiRouter = express.Router();

// maps /api/forecast/whatever to http://api.darksky.net/forecast/developerKey/whatever
// and pipes the response back

const apiKey = "yourAPIKeyHere";

apiRouter.get("/*", (req, res, next) => {
    // parse out action and params
    // from an incoming URL of /api/forecast/42.3601,-71.0589
    // the /api will be the root of the router (so not in the URL here)
    // "forecast" will be the action
    // "42.3601,-71.0589" will be the params

    let parts = req.path.slice(1).split("/"); // split into path segments, skipping leading /
    let action = parts[0];                    // take first path segment as the action
    let params = parts.slice(1).join("/");    // take everything else for params
    request({
        uri: `https://api.darksky.net/${action}/${apiKey}/${params}`,
        method: "get"
    }).pipe(res);
});

app.use("/api", apiRouter);

app.listen(80);
```

Now, when you send this server, this request:

```
 /api/forecast/42.3601,-71.0589
```

it will request:

```
 https://api.darksky.net/forecast/yourAPIKeyHere/42.3601,-71.0589
```

and pipe the result back to the caller.  I ran this test app and it worked for me.  While I didn't see anything other than forecast URLs in the darksky.net API, it would work for anything of the format `/api/someAction/someParams`.

Note, you probably do NOT want to enable CORS on your server because you don't want other people's web pages to be able to use your proxy.  And, since you're just sending requests to your own server now, you don't need CORS to be able to do that.

Comment: @Rwood219 -  Look at the simple little proxy I wrote and added to my answer.  Because you need to insert the APIKey into the URL (you don't want to put that in the client, just keep it in the server only), it appears you can't use any of the pre-built proxy modules on NPM.  But, if your'e just doing GET requests, your own little custom proxy is actually pretty simple.